# Converting scipy sparse coo matrix to networkx graph and back does not yield original matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, networkx, graph-theory

I'm doing data analysis on mass cytometry data and I'm experimenting with graph clustering. At some point in my fiddling I made a scipy sparse matrix in coo format, converted it to a networkx graph and reverted it back again.

```
data.shape
```

(20000, 32)

20000 items (cells) with 32-dimensions (abundance of biological molecule)

```
#Create sparse matrix with distance as edge
knn = kneighbors_graph(data.values, n_neighbors=30, mode='distance')
coo = knn.tocoo()
coo
```

<20000x20000 sparse matrix of type ''
    with 600000 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

20000 nodes with 600000 edges as expected when searching for 30 neighbours

```
#Build undirected weighted nx graph
nxgraph = nx.Graph(knn)
nxgraph.number_of_edges()
```

468258

Lower number of edges, but not half

```
#Back to coo
cooafter = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(nxgraph, format='coo')
cooafter
```

<20000x20000 sparse matrix of type ''
    with 936516 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

Double the number of edges of test

Perhaps I insufficiently understand these datastructures, and this behaviour is completely logical. However, I was expecting conversion to a networkx graph and back to result in the same graph, can anyone explain why coo and cooafter do not have the same number of edges?

Comment: `Graph` is a data structure for an undirected graph, i.e. if the edge (u,v) exists, the edge (v, u) also exists. Your initial network in COO format is directed; converting to an undirected graph hence doubles the number of edges. You should not run into this issue when using the `DiGraph` class.

Comment: Thank you Paul, using a DiGraph indeed yields the same matrix after conversion. The thought had occured to me but I must have made a mistake testing the coo -> DiGraph -> coo conversion.